# If I change my iTunes payment method after making a purchase, which one is used?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, billing

As explained [here](https://www.lifewire.com/why-delay-in-itunes-store-billing-2000485), there is often a delay of anywhere from a few hours  to a couple of days between an iTunes/App Store purchase being made and the payment going through.

If I change my payment information after making a purchase, but before I am billed, which one will be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying it; it seems that the payment is taken from the card set up at the time of purchase.

Comment: This is helpful information. Can you accept your own answer to easily indicate that this answer worked. Thank You.

Comment: @Madhu I intend to, but can’t for another day.

Comment: I think that's some kind of new user restriction. I have upvoted the answer. Please accept it tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @Madhu still says tomorrow.